# Xml scale animation of ImageView makes the image aliased

Tags: android, animation, filter, imageview

I have a little xml animation that animates few ImageViews inside my layout. Actually it is the wavescale animation from the api demos sdk example. This animation scales the image up and then down to its original size so it looks sort of wave. The problem is when the image is upscaled it looks very bad, the edges are aliased and the image is blocky. 
My animation looks like this:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="100" />
    <scale
        android:fromXScale="0.5" android:toXScale="1.25"
        android:fromYScale="0.5" android:toYScale="1.25"
        android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="200" />
    <scale 
        android:fromXScale="1.25" android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.25" android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%"
        android:startOffset="200"
        android:duration="100" />
</set>
```

I tried, instead of loading the image directly in the src of the ImageView, to wrap it in a xml bitmap element and enable antialiasing and filtering but it makes no difference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/myimage_img"
    android:antialias="true"
    android:filter="true"
    android:tileMode="disabled"
/>
```

And my ImageView looks like this:

```
<ImageView android:src="@drawable/myimage" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="5dp" android:adjustViewBounds="true" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:scaleType="centerInside"></ImageView>
```

Please also note that the image is not really upscaled. The image itself is bigger that it appears on the screen. It is centered inside the ImageView. But looks like the animation is not using the original image to render it with different size, but using the downscaled image from the ImageView and scaling it up again.

Can you please help me to make my image appear smooth when it is animated?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the proper image size based on your device DPI? Even though an image looks large on your PC screen, an image may be small on the phone's screen due to a larger number of dots per inch. If this is the case, Android will have to scale the image up.

Comment: Yes, I have the proper image size. As I mentioned the image is actually downscaled and I also tested with both small and high dpi on both emulator and real device and there is no difference - the behavior is still as I describe above.